# Is it worthwhile to do a Best of Hinduism.SE 2016?

Tags: discussion, suggestions

I have seen [here](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9423/best-of-pse-2016-description-categories-and-results) and [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10938/best-of-ppcg-2016-call-for-categories) where a "Best of Year" style event has been done as part of efforts to bolster the community. Do you think the time has come to do a similar albeit smaller scale version (given the size of our SE compared to the other SE mentioned) to celebrate the outstanding contributions and the committed users? It can help improve visibility of great answers, act as a morale boost for our contributors and help new users to integrate better and understand what is expected of them! Moreover, it can also serve as an summary almanac for the year, help the community articulate its culture and bring to focus fresh avenues of research for the year ahead.